# User property in controller aren't authenticated when doing WebRequest with credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, credentials, networkcredentials

I have this code on the client:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
request.Method = "GET";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
request.Credentials = credentials.Credentials; //is a NetworkCredential

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

On the Server side I have a MVC application and trying to get the Users Credetials by

```
User.Identity
```

But It's IsAuthenticated property says false and the other properties are empty. I wish to have a User object that's Authenticated and usable with the IsInRole function.
Guessing that this is an config thing? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Have you already set up authentication and authorization in web.config? Its quite possible your protected pages are being accessed by unauthenticated or unauthorized users, which is why `IsAuthenticated` is false. In IIS, go to your website and check the values for Authentication and Authorization.

Comment: the iis have the following authentication settings: anonym - enabled, impersonation - disabled, basic - enabled, digest - enabled, forms - disabled, windows- enabled. If I turn anonym off I get a 401 respons when I do the request. One other detail: The client isn't on the same domain as the server. (I know the credentials are right becase if I write something else there it gives me 401 even if I have anonym - enabled on the iis)

Comment: the credentials that I'm using is windows-AD accounts (that is diffrent to the windows account the clients host computer is logged in to)

Comment: Looks like there is a gateway in between doing some trix.

Comment: Do you have pages on your website that require anonymous access? If not, turn off Anonymous in IIS and make sure you have `<authentication mode="Windows">` in your web.config. Otherwise, if you need anonymous access for some portions of you website, make sure you authenticate the user before they can get to your view.